# Trying to approximate Riemann sum with $\sin(\frac{x}{5})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-verification, riemann-sum

Let $P= 0, \frac{1}{2},1,2$

Find the upper, lower, and exact area and whether the lower or upper sum is more accurate

Starting with the left:

LH: $$\sin(0)(\frac{1}{2}-0)+\sin(\frac{.5}{5})(1-\frac{1}{2})+\sin(\frac{1}{5})(2-1)$$

$$0+.0499+.19=.248$$

RH:

$$\sin(\frac{.5}{5})(\frac{1}{2}-0)+\sin(\frac{1}{5})(1-\frac{1}{2})+\sin(\frac{2}{5})(2-1)$$

$$=.0499+.19+.389=.61$$

Neither of these is close to the book which says that the sum approximately equal to $.5386$ is closest. What is wrong with my calculation?

Comment: You indicated $\sin(\frac15)\frac12=.19$, but I get $.099$

Comment: You should also use $P=1.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot $\color{red}{\left(1-\dfrac12\right)}$:

$$\sin\left(\frac{.5}{5}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-0\right)+\sin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\color{red}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\sin\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)(2-1)$$

$$\approx.0499+.1987\times\color{red}{\frac12}+.3894$$

$$\approx.5386$$

Comment: Note:  for small $x, $ $\sin x \approx x$